# UWP and User database - Microsoft/Google/Facebook?

Tags: synchronization, win-universal-app, datastore, account

I have a question about how I can save a user database into certain online accounts like Google, Facebook and Microsoft. I really can´t figure out how this Task can be achived. I know that some applications on the store are able to connect and synch data between your devices and your Microsoft account. All you have to do is Login into your MS account.

I have a simple Project for saving and sharing Passwords/License keys. 
Actually I´m working with SQLite but my Problem is... If the user delete the app on e.g. his Windows Phone, he has to create all data entries again.

So I´m looking for some possibilities to avoid this Scenario. 
I want the user to select between 3 cases on Login Screen - (MS authentication, Google authentication, local storage - No account required).

If he had Chosen the MS authentication, all of its data has to be save somewhere and the user can restore and synch all of its entries on all devices. In case of uninstall, the data will be stored in the online storage. If he wishes to use the app again, he has to authenticate to get his data back.

I´m not quite sure if this is correct... For example you can use FireBase for Android. It is a real time data pushing Service, which store and push data Server side.

I hope you have some good advices for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best option is probably to use [App Service - Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/appservice-mobileapps/). With this solution, you can:

- Store the data online (SQL Database)
- Sync offline into a local database (SQL Lite)
- Manage Authentication with Google/Microsoft/Facebook/...

You can use this backend for your Windows application, and also for Android/iOS if needed. Backend logic can be created in .NET or node.js.

Comment: That is great.

I´m definitely going to check this out. But what about prices ?
Is there a free version of this Service ? Are there some restrictions ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have a free version to dev/test. But you probably need more once in production. You can find prices on the following document : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/. Note: If you are a student or a startup, there is some offers to use these resources with no cost (for example Dreamspark/Bizpark program).

Comment: I am a stundent and I have access to Dreamspark. But unfortunately I can not find Azure in my collection (Mobile SDK, .NET SDK, only).